# Sending Newsletters from Django

Tags: django, newsletter

I am seeking advice from someone with experience integrating django and newsletters.

I need to send newsletters from my django app.  I see that there are a couple of packages that already do this such as 'pennyblack' and 'emencia'.    Does anyone have experience with these?  Which of these is the most versatile and easy to use?   My users want to add their own content to the news letters with topic, and article.  News letters generally have 3 articles with a couple of photos.   I also want the newsletter to print nicely as both html and pdf formats.  Any working expamples I could toy with before I dive into the code?

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this with Django? I would suggest you to write your own module or search for other modules. There are a lot of tutorials out there how to send mails with Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can send html email messages directly from django with a few lines of python code, as in this snippet: http://www.djangofoo.com/250/sending-html-email.  Or you can use an email sending module (I like [django-messages](http://code.google.com/p/django-mailer/) - it allows for html and plaintext variants and gives you a message queue).  Of course, that doesn't help you manage the newsletter, so you'd have to do that yourself and render an html template the same way you do with any webpage.  I assume you've already checked google for newsletter-specific django modules with more features, but I don't know of any.

However, you probably don't want to send a newsletter yourself through django (more importantly, from your own production server).  For one thing, if it's going to a lot of people, you don't want it to use all of your bandwidth and make your site sluggish while a huge queue of emails is sent.  But more importantly, it's easy to get your server blacklisted by spam filters if you're not sending from a known, reputable domain (if you're paying for hosting it might be less of an issue, but you should check with your hosting provider).

IMO, your best bet is to use a stand-alone email newsletter service like MailChimp or Cheetah Mail.  I've used and highly recommend [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com) for a small to medium number of recipients, but I imagine there are a bunch of others that do that same thing.  It makes organizing your message campaigns and recipient lists easy with hooks to do things like add a new user on your site to a recipient list.  I'm sure you could also figure out a way to get your user-submitted content into the newsletter from django.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

check this out. A better solution for you is [django-newsletter](http://django-newsletter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html)